# Cocoa Autolayout issue - NSTextView inside a custom NSView

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsview, nstextview, nslayoutanchor

I'm currently writing a Cocoa app, in Swift to exercise the language. I'm not too familiar with the AppKit framework yet, but now I bumped into an interesting problem.

It simply contains an NSWindow, and my custom NSView inside. With autolayout I control the size of the NSView, depending the resized window.

[Base structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AN7n.png)

As for my custom view, I'd like to have my NSView as a container, and I have an NSTextView inside it.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class Fucky2View: NSView 
{
    var textView : NSTextView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) 
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) 
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit()
    {
        print("initing")

        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor

        textView = NSTextView.init(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(textView)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    func displayText(_ text : String)
    {
        let attrStr : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text+"\n") 
        textView.textStorage?.append(attrStr)
    }
}
```

So I just want to keep the NSTextView as same size as the view itself. I colored the view background to red, to see if its filling properly, but this is what happens:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTQndoGzzEM

The textview's height is sometime set properly, but most of the times not.

**I recreated the same exact app with UIKit, UIViewController, UIView and UITextView, tested on iPhone (I resized the screen with rotation), and this was working correctly.**

Do anyone has any idea? I played along with priorities, but did not helped. Tried several things from NSView, concurrent draw, etc, did not helped.
Tried with NSLayoutConstraint instead of anchors, no change. 
The only thing was if I set the TextView's frame in the custom NSView's drawRect: method, but I would like to do a nicer solution.

Or has anyone any other idea?
macOS Sierra 10.12.6, XCode 9.2

Thanks

Comment: `NSTextView` is usually used inside a scroll view and adjusts its size to the text. Why is the height of the text view a problem?

Comment: The NSTextView is fully capable to handle long text with scrolling alone, it does not need an outer scrollview. 

So I put my NSTextView inside an NSView, which acts like a container for the whole component. My goal is that the NSTextView should always be the same size as its NSView container. But the autolayout only affects the NSView (the container) correctly, the NSTextView (the content of the container) is sometime the same size, but mostly not.
And this works as intended with UIKit, so with UIView and UITextView, the anchors and such are set correctly. Just the AppKit looks buggy.

Comment: `NSTextView` ≠ `UITextView`. How do you make `NSTextView` scroll without a `NSScrollView`?

Comment: You are right, on my first try, I drag and dropped an NSTextView from the interface builder, but in that case it cramps up a whole lot of other stuff too, and also it tricked me that the NSTextView has scrolling related methods like scrollToEndOfDocument (which is coming from NSResponder). I just started to extract several functionality from the main app to different components and classes, and I assumed that the NSTextView will work as intended. Anyway, even if I include the TextView into a scrollview, I doubt it will solve the internal resizing problem, I originally asked. But I try.

Comment: Interesting, the NSScrollView is resizing properly with the NSView, when I using the same anchors as I did with the NSTextView. So I replaced the NSView's content from NSTextView to NSScrollView, and the resizing is working ok now (ofc now I cant write out anything, until I put a textview into the scrollview, but I wanted to test out the resizing clean)

So is this a glitch of the TextView? Or the TextView is only working properly in a scrollview, for other multiline display (if I want to show 10 lines for example, and not need to scroll) just use NSTextField?

Comment: The NSTextView is doing the same in the NSScrollView as in the NSView before. 
https://i.imgur.com/Sv7N23p.png
The main NSView (the container of my component, red) is controlled by the autolayout constraints I set up in the main XIB, I have an NSScrollview (yellow) in the nsview, and I have the NSTextView (blue) in a subview in the scrollview. The scrollview's anchors are related to the main NSView, and I tried that the textviews anchors to depend upon the scrollview's or the main container's anchors, but no success. Still flickers between wrong height and correct height (as on my video)

Comment: Why do you want to put `NSTextView` inside a subview? Use `NSTextView` inside a scroll view like the template in IB, without constraints. Take a look at the wrapping multi-line `NSTextField`, maybe it is more like what you want.

Comment: I just want to create a custom component, which can be drag and dropped into a xib to work as intended, which can display messages however i want, and by encapsulating every functionality it needs for that. I want this component to be just a class, no xib, no other. We do this approach all the time in my workplace, but there we create ios apps, not macos. Being in a subview makes me able to have other stuff in that container view, which can affect the textview aferwards. For that, the first step is to have a container with just a textview in it (or a scroll and textview)